# Add several records in moodle

Tags: moodle

I've been having trouble adding items in my table in moodle, this is what I've trying with no success.

```
$totalrec = array();
$rec2 = $DB->get_records('table1', null, '', '*', 0, 0);
$rec4 = $DB->get_records('table2', array('x' => 'y') , '', '*', 0, 0);

foreach ($rec2 as $records2) {
    $rec3 = $DB->get_records('z', array('m' => 'n') , '', '*', 0, 0);
    foreach ($rec3 as $records3) {
        if (isset($_REQUEST['a']) && isset($_REQUEST['b'])) {
            $ca = $_REQUEST['a'];
            $co = $_REQUEST['b'];
            $pi = $records2->idp;
            $recorsh = new class ();

            $recorsh->id = $records2->id;
            $recorsh->te = $co;
            $recorsh->idt = $ti;
            $recorsh->res = $ca;
            $recorsh->ida = $idaud;
            $totalrec[$n] = array($recorsh);
            $n++;
        }
    }
}

$lastinsertid2 = $DB->insert_records('table4', $totalrec);
```

and, this one:

```
$rec2 = $DB->get_records('table1', null, '', '*', 0, 0);
$rec4 = $DB->get_records('table2', array('x' => 'y') , '', '*', 0, 0);

foreach($rec2 as $records2) {
    $rec3 = $DB->get_records('z', array('m' => 'n') , '', '*', 0, 0);
    foreach($rec3 as $records3) {
        if (isset($_REQUEST['a']) && isset($_REQUEST['b'])) {
            $ca = $_REQUEST['a'];
            $co = $_REQUEST['b'];
            $pi = $records2->idp;
            $recorsh = new class ();

            $recorsh->id = $records2->id;
            $recorsh->te = $co;
            $recorsh->idt = $ti;
            $recorsh->res = $ca;
            $recorsh->ida = $idaud;
            $lastinsertid = $DB->insert_record('table4', $recorsh, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Both of them gives me a "Error writing to database" but doesn't say anything specific, I know that I'm not doing the inserting "in the right way" but I don't know how to do it, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure debugging is set to developer ( HTTPS://docs.moodle.org/en/Debugging ), then you should get a more meaningful error. Also use required_param / optional_param, not $_REQUEST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because the ID is added to each object before inserting.

```
$recorsh->id = $records2->id;
```

Like davosmith says, during development always have debugging set to developer level.

In your config.php have this

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);

$CFG->debug = E_ALL | E_STRICT; // 32767;
$CFG->debugdisplay = true;
```

Also never ever use $_REQUEST or $_GET or $_POST directly. This can introduce SQL injection.

Use

```
$a = optional_param('a', null, PARAM_XXX);
$b = optional_param('b', null, PARAM_XXX);
```

or

```
$a = required_param('a', PARAM_XXX);
$b = required_param('b', PARAM_XXX);
```

Change PARAM_XXX to the type of parameter you are expecting. eg `PARAM_INT`, `PARAM_BOOL` etc.